# Build error with assembly missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

When i build my xamarin forms application i am getting the following exception please tell me how to fix it

> Error Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'SQLitePCL.raw, Version=0.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'SQLitePCL.raw.dll'
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets

Thanks

Comment: ya i added to xamarin forms and xamarin android project

Answer (score 0):

Well i have seen this behaviour with the System.IO.FileNotFoundException not loading a reference. In my case it was the reference itself. 
In your case the 'SQLitePCL.raw.dll' seems to be incompatible with Xamarin PCL.

I managed to fix this by

1. Remove the reference from my project
2. Add the reference through nuget package manager
3. If you cannot find the reference in nuget, i would suggest checking from the SQL Lite site if this dll you have is compatible with Xamarin.

Also you can check the following walkthrough from the Xamarin web site which includes SQLLite
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/

In this walkthrough you can see that Xamarin is using a nuget package called "SQL Lite.net PCL".

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem and I was able to solve by adding the SQLitePCL.raw.dll assembly reference file by clicking

```
Add Reference>Browse>Packages>SQLitePCL.raw_basic.0.7.1>lib>MonoAndroid>SQLitePCL.raw.dll
```

Make sure you have installed packages from nuget

```
Install-Package sqlite-net-pcl
```

For More Reference please visit
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue: just update installed package in the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all sqlite related references from the project then install sqlite-net-pcl via Nuget and Call SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init() on startup.